# can I use django with flutter?

Tags: django, flutter, rest, mobile, backend

I'm a noob in software development. I need to develop a web application to create and add users for a system. and a mobile app for to users to login. **users can't register with mobile. they have to first register with web application**  can i use a Django with rest APIs to backend as both mobile and web application (mobile app language is dart with flutter)

I read in the documentation that we can use rest API for it. but no clear guide found. I also found we can import user details easily with firebase.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can definitely use Django with REST APIs as the backend for both your web application and mobile application built with Flutter.

Here's a suggested approach:

1. Backend Development with Django:

   - Set up a Django project and create the necessary models to represent users and their data.
   - Implement Django's built-in authentication system or use a third-party library like Django REST Framework (DRF) for user management and authentication.
   - Create RESTful APIs in Django using DRF to handle user registration, login, and any other relevant operations you need for your application.
   - Implement necessary validation and security measures, such as validating user input, protecting sensitive information, and securing API endpoints with authentication and permissions.
2. Web Application Development:

   - Develop the web application using Django's template system or a frontend framework like React, Angular, or Vue.js that integrates with Django.
   - Create user registration and user management views/pages in your web application. These views will communicate with the Django backend through the REST APIs you created.
   - Implement form validation, error handling, and any other frontend functionality specific to the web application.
3. Mobile Application Development with Flutter:

   - Build your mobile application using Flutter and Dart.
   - Use Flutter's HTTP client libraries like `http` or `dio` to communicate with the Django REST APIs.
   - Implement user login functionality in the mobile app, allowing users to authenticate with their credentials against the Django backend.
   - Design and develop the mobile app's UI, incorporating features such as user profile display, password reset, or any other necessary functionality.

By using Django with REST APIs, you can centralize your backend logic and share it between the web and mobile applications. Both the web and mobile applications can interact with the Django backend through the same API endpoints.

Make sure to plan your API design carefully, considering the data structures and authentication/authorization requirements specific to your application. Following RESTful principles and leveraging the power of Django and Flutter will help you build a robust and scalable solution.